# Is there a way I can use more instances than the number of external IPs I have?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have more than enough CPUs and memory to launch 100 instances but only 30 external IP addresses is there a way I can launch more instances despite that?

Comment: If you need more than 30 public IPs you can request for quota increase by filling the form on this link https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform

Comment: The only reason I have 30 is that I already filled out that form. They seem very reluctant to hand out IPs and I need about 1000 instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you don't need that many IPs at all. Only in very specific scenarios you would need all your nodes to be publicly accessible.

If you need that many instances, simply create them without public IPs. Then, create a [NAT Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) so your instances can use that to access outside your private network.

You will be able to accomplish 99% of usage scenarios this way. If you really need more IPs and you have used all of your ephemeral IPs you can request in the [Form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform).

Comment: Thanks! This looks a lot easier than a squid proxy

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends what you want to do, but the `gcloud compute instances create` tool has a flag `--no-address` which will allow you to launch an instance with no external IP address. Have a look at `gcloud compute instances create --help` to see if you think that would be useful.

If you wanted to use the API or instance templates, I think just leaving out the accessConfigs part of the networking section of the request body will do what you need. Compare this:

```
"networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-here/global/networks/default",
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "name": "External NAT",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Where I used the default option of "Ephemeral" for the external IP in the Google Cloud Developers console, with this:

```
"networkInterfaces": [
    {
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-here/global/networks/default"
    }
  ]
```

Where I selected "None" as the External IP.

To look at what the API body would look like, there is a link "View Equivalent REST" just below the Create button, it can be really useful for templates and things.